# How can I write an MDX statement or query that selects the clients who paid last month but have not paid this(Current Month) month?.

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

How can I write an MDX statement or query that selects the clients who paid last month but  have not paid this(Current Month) month?. I have a data cube designed and deployed on Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services R 2. I have a customer dimensions and a fact table.
 Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a [Time] dimension, and a measure that contains a value if the client has paid. I think the `Filter()` function will help you reduce a set of all clients down to just the clients that you're interested in.

`SELECT {Filter({[Client].[SomeLevel].members}, ([Time].[LastMonth], [Measures].[whatever]) > 0 AND ([Time].[ThisMonth], [Measures].[whatever]) = 0} ON ROWS, {[Measures].[whatever]} ON COLUMNS FROM [CubeName]`

You trouble might be deciding what to use in place of where I wrote [Time].[ThisMonth] - see other answers here on StackOverflow for selecting 'current' dates.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to identify the current month and the last month. One way to do it is compute it using the `VBA!Date` function.

So if your dates are stored in the format `12/31/2014` and assuming you have a measure `Payment` and a Date dimension with a `Year-Quarter-Month-Date` hierarchy, the below code can help you.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].ValueThisMonth AS
(
 [Date].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT, 
 [Measures].[Payment]
)

MEMBER [Measures].ValueLastMonth AS
(
 [Date].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT.LAG(1), 
 [Measures].[Payment]
)

SELECT [Client].[Client Name].MEMBERS
HAVING ISEMPTY([Measures].ValueThisMonth)
AND NOT(ISEMPTY([Measures].ValueLastMonth))
ON 0
FROM [Your cube]
WHERE 
StrToMember("[Date].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].[Date].&[" + FORMAT(VBA![Date](), "MM/dd/yyyy") + "]" + "]")
```

If instead you would like to pass this "current" value from the front end, use a parameter in the `WHERE` clause.